# Flex3 - Remote messaging not working with SSL certificates on Tomcat server

Tags: java, ssl, apache-flex, tomcat8, blazeds

```
<channel-definition id="my-secure-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.SecureAMFChannel">
    <endpoint url="https://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amfsecure" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.SecureAMFEndpoint"/>
    <properties>
        <polling-enabled>false</polling-enabled>
        <serialization>
            <instantiate-types>false</instantiate-types>
        </serialization>
        <add-no-cache-headers>false</add-no-cache-headers>
    </properties>
</channel-definition>
```

The above configuration changes are done in the `services-config.xml` file and kept the corresponding certificate file under WEB-INF folder.

in the developer tool, http://app:8090/messageBroker/amf is showing instead of "https" url with secure-amf

https://app:8090/SV/home instead of this its sending an URL with http://app:8090/SV/home which is not expected.